# How can I debug a stuck cockroachdb upgrade?

Tags: cockroachdb

I'm seeing signs that my CockroachDB cluster isn't able to finalize a version upgrade: `SHOW CLUSTER SETTING version` shows a version older than the binary's version, and I'm getting errors when trying to use new features or run commands that reference system tables. How can I find out why it's not upgrading?

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```sql
SET CLUSTER SETTING version = crdb_internal.node_executable_version();
```

You should get an informative error message explaining why it can't do that. Stuck upgrades almost always indicate a bug and should be reported to Cockroach Labs ([via a Github issue](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/new?assignees=&labels=C-bug&template=bug_report.md&title=) or other support channels).